# UIView not correctly applying autolayout to fill 100% width of parent

Tags: ios, uiview, uistoryboard

I am building an iOS interface in Storyboard. I have a custom view named `LevelsView` which inherits from `UIView`, which I want to fill the lower half of the screen. This custom view is the child of a parent `UIViewController`/`UIView`.

The two following images might help illustrate, where the green area is the `LevelsView`:

[image: layout]

[image: constraints]

As you can see, I've added a leading space and a trailing space constraint to the superview, in an attempt to make it match the width of the superview, and hence the screen. However, at runtime the width doesn't ever change - it's always the width as it appears in storyboard (600px). How can I make the `LevelsView` fluidly fill 100% of its superview?

Two further notes of which I'm not sure have any impact:

- Although I'm building a custom UIView-derived view, the same problem occurs when I use a plain old UIView in its place.
- I'm building this app in Swift, though I'm not aware of any bugs that affect IB.

I apologise if this has been answered elsewhere - I can't find anything but it seems like it should be a common question.

Comment: can you expand out the levels view and see if there are any constraints hidden in there?  Not all constraints (as I'm sure you're aware) show up in the outermost Constraints list

Comment: Sorry @mckeejm should have done that already. The only hidden constraint is a set height on the `LevelsView`